# Como fazer uma função dentro de outra

Tags: javascript, legenda-de-gráfico

Olá, estou tentando fazer legendas .ass rodar em um vídeo, consegui achar essa [API](https://github.com/weizhenye/ASS), porem preciso executar dentro do click de um botão, mas quando chega na linha `x.onreadystatechange = function()` ele para de executar, como posso arrumar isso ??

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).on('click', '.class', function()
    {
        var videoLink = 'videos/video.mkv';
        var subtitle = 'videos/subtitle.ass';

        document.getElementById("video").remove();
        var videoHTML = ['<video id="video" class="video" autoplay controls>',
                             '<source src="'+videoLink+'"/>',
                         '</video>'].join('');

        document.getElementById("videoContainer").innerHTML = videoHTML;

        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open('GET', subtitle, 1);
        x.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (x.readyState === 4 && x.status === 200) 
            {
                var ass = new ASS();
                ass.init(x.responseText, document.getElementById('video'));
            }
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: O video estava executando antes da playlista carregar?

Comment: Eu coloco o código do vídeo com `InnerHtml` e a propriedade autoplay antes de chamar essa funcionalidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente adicionar o `.play()`, outro detalhe, **falta o `send()`** no teu Ajax, o `autoplay` não parece necessário, basta executar o `play` assim que a legenda for iniciada.

**Um detalhe importante**, isto **não existe**:

```
 document.getElementById("video").remove();
```

A função `.remove` não existe em `DOM`, você deve ter confudido a lib jQuery com JS puro, isso é que deve ter dado o erro todo, faça tudo com jQuery mesmo:

```
$(document).on('click', '.class', function()
{
    var videoLink = 'videos/video.mkv';
    var subtitle = 'videos/subtitle.ass';

    var video = $("#video");
    var videoContainer = $("#videoContainer");

    //Remove o video anterior
    videoContainer.html("");

    var videoHTML = ['<video class="video" controls>',
                         '<source src="'+videoLink+'"/>',
                     '</video>'].join('');

    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open('GET', subtitle, 1);
    x.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (x.readyState === 4)
        {
            if (x.status !== 200) {
                alert("Erro ao requisitar:" + x.status);
                return;
            }

            //Atualiza a variável do video com o novo video
            video = $(videoHTML);

            //Adiciona o video ao container
            video.appendTo(videoContainer);
            var c = video.get(0);

            setTimeout(function () {
               var ass = new ASS();

               c.play();

               //video.get(0) pega o video como DOM e passa para o ASS.init
               ass.init(x.responseText, c);
            }, 100);
        }
    };

    x.send(null); //**FALTAVA ISTO**
});
```

### Um exemplo funcional

```js
$(document).on('click', '.class', function()
{
    var videoLink = 'https://ass.js.org/test.mp4';
    var subtitle = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Aegisub/Aegisub/master/docs/specs/ass-format-tests.ass';
    var video = $("#video");
    var videoContainer = $("#videoContainer");

    //Remove o video anterior
    videoContainer.html("");

    var videoHTML = ['<video class="video" controls>',
                         '<source src="'+videoLink+'"/>',
                     '</video>'].join('');

    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open('GET', subtitle, 1);
    x.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (x.readyState === 4)
        {
            if (x.status !== 200) {
                alert("Erro ao requisitar:" + x.status);
                return;
            }

            //Atualiza a variável do video com o novo video
            video = $(videoHTML);

            //Adiciona o video ao container
            video.appendTo(videoContainer);
            var c = video.get(0);

            setTimeout(function () {
               var ass = new ASS();

               c.play();

               //video.get(0) pega o video como DOM e passa para o ASS.init
               ass.init(x.responseText, c);
            }, 100);
        }
    };

    x.send(null); //**FALTAVA ISTO**
});
```

```css
.video {
    width: 480px;
    height: 320px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//rawgit.com/weizhenye/ASS/master/dist/ass.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div id="videoContainer"></div>

<p>
    <a class="class" href="#">Iniciar</a>
</p>
```

No **Jsfiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/cp8d1t6y/2/

Comment: O problema é que ele nem entra nessa parte, é o vídeo está com autoplay

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta já, lembrando que eu já testei em outra classe com o código que a API da de exemplo e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: @LucasCarezia resposta atualizada, tinham dois erros graves no teu script

Comment: Fiz da forma que você disse, e retornou esse erro `Classroom Crisis:48 Uncaught ReferenceError: ASS is not defined
    at XMLHttpRequest.x.onreadystatechange`

Comment: Na verdade eu insiro os dois para ter certeza `<script src="ass.min.js"></script> <script src="ass.js"></script>`.

Comment: Tudo bem, eu estou aprendendo linguagem Web, então acredito que não tenha problema errar, eu não sabia sobre o arquivo ser compactado ou não, obrigado pela informação.

Comment: Mas já que você está fazendo o exemplo, poderia me informar como fazer a legenda se adaptar quando o usuário colocar o vídeo em fullscreen ??

Comment: Tudo bem, fico esperando aqui.

Comment: @LucasCarezia veja que eu atualizei a resposta, deixei um exemplo do e um link no jsfiddle.